# GoLand not showing individual test results after test run

Tags: unit-testing, go, goland

I am trying to fix some unit tests in GoLand using the (I believe) standard "testing" package in Go, but I'm having trouble figuring out which test is failing. After I run the tests, there is nothing shown in the test results dropdown, it is just empty (see below).

I wrote a dummy empty test that just prints "here" to test if it worked on just a simple test, and even then I get no test results in the explorer. The test passes and prints the expected output.

```
func Test_ResultsShow(t *testing.T) {
    println("here")
}
```

```
=== RUN   Test_ResultsShow
here
--- PASS: Test_ResultsShow (0.00s)
PASS

Process finished with the exit code 0
```

[image]

Additionally, when I try to run my larger suite of tests, the number of passed (24) and failed (1) tests don't add up to the total number of tests indicated (26). I see no indication of any test failure in the test output either, and I've run all the tests individually to see which test is failing, but all of them succeeded.

The blacked out section below is covers the repository name. But the individual test names are not shown below it (though they are confirmed to run by the output).

[image]

Comment: Passed tests are hidden by default, you should enable Show Passed checkbox: https://imgur.com/UmaVOmb

What version of GoLand are you using? Is there a chance to share these test samples?